# Pandas: Optimizing multiple similar activities on one flask page

Tags: pandas

I am a teacher.  I use GoogleClassroom to manage assignments and grades and Flask website and the GoogleClassroom API to build a dashboard for me and for students. As I learn more about the tools I am using I am wondering about optimization.  There are two lists of dictionaries I use regularly. Assignments which can be maybe 50 dictionaries and student submissions which can be 50*100 dictionaries.  I have a statistics page where I do three different analysis: 1) on time percentage y student, 2) current assignment sate by assignment, 3) number of times students are turning in each assignment to get a better grade. At the moment, for each of these three calculations I do the whole process of

1. turning the dictionaries into a dataframe
2. some basic shaping/cleaning of the data
3. pivot,
4. merge,
5. style.

Are some of these things more intensive than others and I should try to combine them? How should I go about optimizing something like this?